# Msbuild 15 includes config files not set as "do not copy"

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild-15

We are wanting to start using MSbuild 15 instead of MSBuild 14.
We have a small problem though.

Previously in MSBuild 14, when a file was marked in Visual Studio as "Do not copy" in the "Copy to Output Directory" setting on the file properties, then it didn't create a .dll.config file. 
But now using MSBuild 15, it does create a .dll.config file.

Is there a way in MSBuild 15 to not copy the file? As it creates backward compatibility problems.

[image: Visual Studio Config File]

[image: Config File Setting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. 
You need to add /p:AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions=none as a command line parameter for MSBuild 15 builds. It's not needed for MSBuild 14 builds.

[MSBuild Github Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1307)